# elixir metaprogramming for module attributes

Tags: macros, elixir, metaprogramming

I have this module

```
defmodule ElixirMeta.LangLoader do

  @external_resource [Path.join([__DIR__, "es.json"]),
                      Path.join([__DIR__, "en.json"])]

  defmacro __using__(_) do
    for lang <- ["es", "en"] do
      {:ok, body} = File.read(Path.join([__DIR__, "#{lang}.json"]))
      {:ok, json} = Poison.decode(body)
      quote do
        def lang(unquote(lang)), do: unquote(Macro.escape(json))
      end
    end
  end
end

defmodule ElixirMeta.Lang do
  use ElixirMeta.LangLoader
end
```

I know I can define a function like:

```
def lang(unquote(lang)), do: unquote(Macro.escape(json))
```

And can be called like this:

```
Lang.lang("es")
```

Also even modify it's function name, like this:

```
def unquote(:"lang_#{lang}")(), do: unquote(Macro.escape(json))
```

And be called like this:

```
Lang.lang_es
```

But is it possible to do the same with a module attribute?

And being the module attribute compiled (?) I think is not possible to initialize it from the macro? maybe I would have to do it within `before_compile` macro?

I would like to access, for the purpose of the example, `Lang.lang_es` as a `@lang_es` and `@lang_en` `LangLoader` attributes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, one can achieve that with [`Module.put_attribute/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html#put_attribute/3) (I have created an MCVE out of your initial code):

```rb
defmodule ElixirMeta.LangLoader do
  defmacro __using__(_) do
    [
      (quote do: Module.register_attribute __MODULE__,
        :langs, accumulate: true) |
      for lang <- ["es", "en"] do
        quote do
          def lang(unquote(lang)), do: unquote(lang)
          Module.put_attribute __MODULE__,
            :"lang_#{unquote(lang)}", unquote(lang)
          Module.put_attribute __MODULE__,
            :langs, unquote(lang)
        end
      end
    ]
  end
end

defmodule ElixirMeta.Lang do
  use ElixirMeta.LangLoader

  def test do
    IO.inspect {
      @lang_es,
      Enum.find(@langs, & &1 == "es"),
      lang("es")
    }, label: "Variants"
  end
end

ElixirMeta.Lang.test
#⇒ Variants: {"es", "es", "es"}
```

The code above declares the accumulated attribute (`@attr  :foo` followed by `@attr :bar` would produce `[:foo, :bar]` value instead of overwriting the attribute value, single attribute and the function.

Please note, that there is no way to access module attribute from outside, since module attributes are compile-time entities.